# What is turbolinks in rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I see in my **application.js** file **//= require turbolinks**. I was wondering what turbolinks does in rails 5.0 because it is somehow getting in the way of my bootstrap buttons. Can someone please explain what turbolinks is and how i can fix my bootstrap problem?

Answer (score 4):

Turbolinks is a gem that speeds up your app and makes it behave like a SPA (Single Page App), it does this by loading only the content between your body tags (using javascript) basically by making and AJAX request to the server, waiting the answer, deleting the old content and replacing it with the new content, handling the URL and browsing history.

For more info check https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Answer (score 3):

### Simple Explanation By Analagy:

Imagine you have a yellow page directory (a physical book directory). Every now and then, one or two phone numbers require updating. Rather than simply ordering an entirely new directory, you simply edit, within the directory itself, the phone numbers that need to be edited.

It's a LOT faster, and less expensive.

How do you know what numbers need to be edited? Well you'd make a phone call (AJAX request) and the yellow pages people will simply tell you that what certain few numbers need changing.

In other words, only the parts of the page which need changing will be changed with turbolinks. The problem with turbolinks is that it might not always be compatible with other javascript libraries out there.